# Extracting multiple occurrences of same field in an XML response in jmeter

Tags: xml, jmeter, response, extract, counter

I am trying to extract an id in SOAP/XML response through Regex extractor.
My exact requirement is:

The SOAP XML should run only once, then I should save all the occurrences of an id.. 
How many times the id will appear in the response is also unknown. It is varying. Can you please give an idea on how the test plan should be set up? I created a counter and gave the counter name in Match No field of the Regex, but something is wrong in the setup.

Regex screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `-1` as Match No.
2. Remove `${Occurrence}` from the "Reference Name"

and it will store all the occurrences in form of:

```
dlDRef_1=foo
dlDRef_2=bar
dlDRef_3=baz
etc.
dlDRef_MatchNr=3
```

Also be aware that a better idea would be using [XPath2 Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) (available from [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)) or [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) for previous JMeter versions as using regular expressions for parsing XML is not the best idea

Comment: Excellent. It worked. What if I need to pass these values to a subsequent request. Because sometimes I may get until dIDRef_20(20 occurences). Sometimes there might be 15. How to tackle that?

Comment: It depends on the format of the next request, most probably it will require some [Groovy scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so I would suggest raising a new question if you won't be able to find out the solution yourself as the answer might not fit into the comments section and it looks like a separate topic